# can I do this "action" with pure CSS2?

Tags: javascript, css

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/AcHPu/) code :

```
<ul class="main">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>                
    </li>                    

    <li>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <ul class="second">            
            <li>Hello</li>
        </ul>                        
    </li>                                
</ul>​

.second
{
    display:none;
}​
```

And I'd like, when I am with the mouse over the link (`a:hover`) set `display:block` to the ul `second` inside the li on the first level. Than, When I'll left the link with mouse, back it to none.

Is it possible with CSS or only javascript?

Answer (score 3):

Of course, it is possible

```
ul.second { display: none; }
a:hover + ul.second { display: block; }
```

and it will even work in most modern browsers.

Not sure, whether `+` selector does belong to `CSS2`, though.

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes, just use the a:link, a:visited, a:hover and a:active pseudo-classes.

I'm taking a wild guess here but I think you may mean the list-style attributes to show the enumeration "icons" (or hide them).